# Bivariate distribution joint PMF problem

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, solution-verification

> determine the constant c so that p(x,y) satisfies the conditions of being a joint probability mass function for two discrete random variables
>   $p(x,y)=c(2x+y)$, where $x=1,2, y=1,2,3$

Total probability is $\sum p(x,y)=1 $, and the sample space is $(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(2,1),(2,2),(2,3)$. So the sum is

$$3c+4c+5c+5c+6c+7c=1 \\
\implies c=\frac{1}{30}$$

Is this how we get?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.